# Gap between Hatcher and Steenrod & Epstein

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request

I am currently reading Steenrod & Epstein's book on cohomology operations after finishing Hatcher's book of *Algebraic Topology*. And I am starting from Chapter 5 Equivariant Cohomology. The problem I encounter is that in Steenrod & Epstein's book, there seem to be some terminologies that I have never (or only rarely) seen in Hatcher, and it is hard to find them from the internet either, for example, (equivariant/minimal) carriers, proper maps, regular cell complexes, (equivariant) diagonal approximations, etc. I wonder if these terminologies are still actively used or have they been replaced by more abstract treatment? Are there any references that might introduce these concepts in more detail? I found some explanations of carriers in Munkres' book *Elements of Algebraic Topology* but not the equivariant version. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these terminologies not defined in Steenrod & Epstein?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes they are defined but without any examples or any explanations on motivations of introducing the concepts. And after the definitions, the book quickly moves on to theorems involving these concepts with very brief proofs.

Comment: Your list of terminologies is somewhat all over the map. "Proper maps" are in any topology book, e.g. Munkres. "Regular cell complexes" are just CW complexes (read about those in Hatcher) with the extra condition that characteristic maps are injective. Some other stuff I would suggest perhaps an older algebraic topology book such as Spanier.

Comment: Equivariant things are like ordinary things but... equivariant with respect to a group action.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your help! The definition of a proper map in Steenrod & Epstein is a bit tricky. "A map $f: K \to L$ between two CW complexes is proper if the minimal carrier is cyclic" -- which I suppose here should be "acyclic?". It is not the proper map in standard topology books.

Comment: Oops... okee dokee

Comment: My only other comment is that Steenrod and Epstein should probably not be your first book on characteristic classes beyond Hatcher. I'm not up with more modern treatments, but there is Milnor's book "Characteristic Classes". Any time your mathematical interests cross the subject of one of Milnor's books you have a wonderful opportunity, namely, to read something Milnor wrote. I'll say, though, that in my memory Milnor does punt the issue of existence of Stiefel-Whitney classes, in fact I believe he punts it to... Steenrod and Epstein.

Comment: Milnor and Stasheff define the  stiefel whitney classes via steenrod squares. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milnstas.pdf